# Could someone please create an "Eternals" tag?

Tags: support, tags

A new (2021) Marvel movie: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternals_(film)

Comment: Please do not se meta for such requests. You could simply flag your question to an admin, or wait a little bit until someone added the relevant tag (as I did before I saw this question). Also, this isn't a "feature request".

Comment: @BCdotWEB Why not? If someone lacks the reputation to create tags, using meta for such requests seems reasonable: it doesn't require diamond moderator attention via flags, and waiting might not work if nobody happens to notice the question requires a new tag.

Comment: Yes, and with 1700 reputation, that someone is you.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Ah, see, I had no idea :) Even with my 10 years or so presence and 75k accumulated across the sites i never thought I could just like this, bam, create a tag. Thanks for the info! (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags in case someone is wondering)